# Mysql showing error while creating primary key and foreign key relation between two tables despite of using index

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in Mysql named `customer_details` and `transaction table`.

I have one column `named account_no( primary key in customer_details)` and want to relate with `account_no field(foreign key in transaction table)`. 
But it is showing error saying `Foreign key relation could not be added`.

I tried creating index in both columns but still its not working.

Comment: check the data type as the data type of the child field and the patent field should be the same

Comment: Could you please post the sql query, so it would be easy to find the actual cause.

Comment: Check you have met all the requirements listed here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. If you are still having a problem post your table definition and alter statement (if appropriate).

Comment: @BishnuKayasha If I read this correctly, you created separate indexes on both columns. If that's the case, then the one on  `customer_details`.`account_no` is redundant because the column is the PRIMARY KEY. If you haven't solved this problem yet then post the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables and that might help things along. If you have solved it, let people know how it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `transaction` 
ADD INDEX `FK_Transaction_AccountNo_idx` (`AccountNo` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `transaction` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Transaction_AccountNo`
  FOREIGN KEY (`AccountNo`)
  REFERENCES `customer_details` (`AccountNo`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

collation of both table and column should be equal